# Expandable List in SwiftUI only expands once and won't contract

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm trying (and failing!) to implement an expandable list of questions and answers in SwiftUI.

```
struct FAQ: Equatable, Identifiable {
    static func ==(lhs: FAQ, rhs: FAQ) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
    let id = UUID()
    let question: String
    let answers: [String]
    var isExpanded: Bool = false
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private (set) var faqs: [FAQ] = [
        FAQ(question: "What is the fastest animal on land?", answers: ["The cheetah"]),
        FAQ(question: "What colours are in a rainbox?", answers: ["Red", "Orange", "Yellow", "Blue", "Indigo", "Violet"])
    ]

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(faqs) { faq in
                Section(header: Text(faq.question)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        if let index = self.faqs.firstIndex(of: faq) {
                            self.faqs[index].isExpanded.toggle()
                        }
                    }
                ) {
                    if faq.isExpanded {
                        ForEach(faq.answers, id: \.self) {
                            Text("• " + $0).font(.body)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Tapping any question successfully expands the answers into view, but tapping the same header again doesn't contract the answers, nor does tapping a second question expand those answers.

[image]

With some judiciously placed `print`s, I can see that `isExpanded` is toggled to `true` on the first question tapped, but then won't toggle back to `false`.

*Could someone explain what I'm doing wrong?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with your `@State var faq: [FAQ]` line. The `@State` property wrapper allows your view to watch for changes in your array, but changing a property of one of the array's elements does not count as a change in the array.

Instead of using a state variable, you probably want to create a small view model, like so:

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var faqs: [FAQ] = [
           FAQ(question: "What is the fastest animal on land?", answers: ["The cheetah"]),
           FAQ(question: "What colours are in a rainbox?", answers: ["Red", "Orange", "Yellow", "Blue", "Indigo", "Violet"])
       ]
}
```

and update your ContentView:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(model.faqs.indices) { index in
                Section(header: Text(self.model.faqs[index].question)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        self.model.faqs[index].isExpanded.toggle()
                    }
                ) {
                    if self.model.faqs[index].isExpanded {
                        ForEach(self.model.faqs[index].answers, id: \.self) {
                            Text("• " + $0).font(.body)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `@ObservedObject` property wrapper in your `ContentView` now watches for any changes its `ViewModel` object announces, and the `@Published` wrapper tells the `ViewModel` class to announce anything that happens to the array, including changes to its elements.

Comment: @AshleyMills I updated my answer to iterate over `model.faqs.indices` instead of `model.faqs`. In your original answer, you look over the elements twice, once in `ForEach` and once in `firstIndex(of:)`, making your code run in O(n^2) time. Iterating on the indices makes the code a little more verbose, but much more efficient if you have a lot of faqs in your array.

Answer (score 0):

By splitting the views into smaller self contained views, this can be easily achieved.

The model doesn't need to know whether the answer is displayed in the screen or not. Hence, it is not required to look in the array to know whether a view is expanded.

Also, the entire list need not be redrawn when one of the sections is expanded. For more info on when a view redraws, see [this article](https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/swiftui-why-to-write-custom-views-for-better-performance-561962f1c268).

```
struct FAQ {
    var question: String
    var answers: [String]
}

struct InfoView: View {
    let information: [FAQ] = [
        FAQ(question: "What is the fastest animal on land?", answers: ["The cheetah"]),
        FAQ(question: "What colours are in a rainbox?", answers: ["Red", "Orange", "Yellow", "Blue", "Indigo", "Violet"])
    ]

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(information, id: \.question) { info in
                InfoSection(info: info)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct InfoSection: View {

    let info: FAQ
    @State var showsAnswer = false

    var body: some View {
        Section(header: questionHeader) {
            if showsAnswer {
                ForEach(info.answers, id: \.self) { answer in
                    Text("• " + answer)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    var questionHeader: some View {
        Text(info.question)
            .foregroundColor(.primary)
            .onTapGesture {
            self.showsAnswer.toggle()
        }
    }
}
```